# Answer for a closed question; how?

Tags: support

I think the question https://superuser.com/q/1750696/964771 should not be closed. After some investigation I found the solution (cause of the problem). However with the question being closed I cannot add the answer. What to do?

Answer (score 2):

The deletion was automatic - and I've undeleted it. I have *however* not reopened it - the comments reflect issues with the question that need to be addressed, and if the changes fix these issues, the question could be reopened via the usual routes. Do ensure you have the question in good working order *before* you tick on the box that pushes it back into the queue.

Comment: Actually I had edited the text, but people still think it's not OK. What exactly would you consider inappropriate in the current text?

Comment: @U.Windl - You have to give the community more than an hour to reopen your question

Comment: OK, but the edit is a week ago, actually.

Comment: The question seems to have been deleted at the time of writing this comment.

Comment: apparently community and I are at odds about this :D

Comment: Improving the quality of the question might satisfy the community bot :$